# permission denied trying to set global git config

Tags: windows, git

in visual code terminal, I am trying to create user account with the command `git config --global user.name "Tari shah"`, but I am keep getting the error

> error: could not lock config file C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.gitconfig: Permission denied".

please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GitHub or GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like VSCode was launch with the System account or Administrator account, but *not* your own Windows account.

Try the same command in a regular CMD session, opened regularely (not as admin): it should write in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`.
You can see that with (using Git 2.27):

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

So try and re-launch your VSCode from your Windows account.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try that.